# Is it possible to create variables in the doT.js templating engine?

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I am using [doT.js](http://olado.github.com/doT/index.html), a javascript templating engine. I would like to know if it is possible to use (helper-) variables like in the following example:

```
{{var foo = "bar"}}

<div>{{=foo}}</div>
```

**Output:**

```
<div>bar</div>
```

The above example does not work, but maybe there is another way. There doesn't seem to be any information about **variables** in the doT.js documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a feature called 'compile-time defines' stated in 'default delimiters' of document. http://olado.github.com/doT/index.html

Examples can be found in https://github.com/olado/doT/blob/master/examples/advancedsnippet.txt

Here's the solution of your problem:

```
{{##def.foo="bar"#}}

<div>{{#def.foo}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{{var foo = "bar";}}
```

Should do the trick.